# spring war contextloader not initialized

Tags: spring, tomcat, maven, spring-mvc

I am using the maven antrun plugin to scp my war file over to a remote tomcat server when i run `mvn install`

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>scp</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <configuration>
            <tasks>
                <scp file="target/somewar.war" todir="bar@foo.com:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/webapps"/>

            </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.42</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Works fine, I managed to copy over the war file. however starting startup.sh, the webapp does not run, it seems that the ContextListener isn't loaded or something and no url seems to be mapped.

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/gohcy/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/ppdf-3party-trusted-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Dec 27, 2012 8:30:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
```

I haven't had such problem with using the same war file in the target folder in my local tomcat. Does anyone knows what could be the problem?

update: I apologize, but it seems like running an md5 checksum yields different results. Is my ant scp task configured correctly?

```
webapps noob$ md5 somewar.war 
MD5 (somewar.war) = e9a7b263f30188df9a76c82ef9459912

[noob@PVM0 webapps]$ md5sum somewar.war 
37142c9902ba9b2d6ab4138c216520e8  somewar.war
```

update: retried, with correct checksum, but same result.

my web.xml, in case i did something wrong here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: are you including spring depdencies in yr tomcat/lib or war folder ? You should be

Comment: @NimChimpsky, yea i included them.please see update.

Comment: check yr logs, check the exploded war looks correct

Comment: the exploded war looked correct. web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml are there.

Comment: change the 2 to a 1. You are specify that the dispatcher servlet is second thing loaded... with nothing set to be the first. It won;t fix problem, but is confusing.

Comment: Try fixing the log4j config.  Odds are you've got a perfectly explanatory log message just waiting for delivery instructions.

Comment: Hi Gus thanks your advice helps and I found my error message. If you would put it in answer or something I will accept it..